# Need help searching through an XML file using jquery and storing results in variable for later use

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, variables, search

I have been searching for the good part of the week for an XML Search method using javascript/jquery - but most methods are for output to HTML or display the entire array of records in XML, which is what I don't want to achieve. The function that I am looking for is to search for a user such as "Sarah", then store the "department" and "code" in corresponding variables; (var department, var code).  I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<phonebook>
<person>
    <first_name>Sarah</first_name>
    <department>Sales</department>
    <code>78</code>
</person>
<person>
    <first_name>Jean-Claude</first_name>
    <department>HR</department>
    <code>90</code>
</person>
</phonebook>
```

How do I go about doing this for an XML file with over 400 records?

Thank you guys. Here is the final working solution for people looking in the future:

```
function ReadXML() {
    try {
        var xmlPath = "../WebResources/new_fruits.xml";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: xmlPath,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXML
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Error while reading XML; Description – " + e.description);
    }
}

function parseXML(xml) {
var $person = $(xml).find('first_name').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "Sarah";
}).closest('person');

var department = $('department', $person).text(); // = Sales
var code = $('code', $person).text(); // = 78    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter`, like this:

```js
function parseXML(xml) {
    var $person = $(xml).find('first_name').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == "Sarah";
    }).closest('person');

    var department = $('department', $person).text(); // = Sales
    var code = $('code', $person).text(); // = 78
}
```

Note that `filter` is a lot quicker than using a `:contains` selector. This difference will be very noticable when 4000 elements are being searched.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should work fine on XML.

```
var doc = $(your-xml-doc-string);
doc.find('person firstname').each(function() {
     var self=$(this);
     console.log(self.text());
});
// or
var sarah = doc.find('person firstname:contains("Sarah")');
```

The [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector should work fine.